# Is there a way to sync geolocation from Lightroom Classic to Mobile?

Tags: lightroom, sync

All my photos are managed in Lightroom Classic (latest version) on my desktop. Most of my pictures are grouped in collections set to "Sync". This way Adobe only syncs smart previews that don't use up my meager 20GB space. I use Lightroom on my tablet and phone (Android in my case) to can browse, organize and edit on the go.

I noticed it doesn't sync location data and I was wondering whether it can be enabled somewhere ?

Comment: I test by sync computer->cloud->mobile RAW with XMP GPS, make some changes and sync back. And I have location data in place. In lightroom mobile there is no way to view/change location data (AFAIK)

Comment: I assumed that I don't see location data in mobile because it didn't sync. Never thought it's not supported. But indeed questions in the Adobe community note that this is not supported.

Edit: if you post it as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience and tests Lightroom mobile do not support view/edit of location information. But when you sync data from desktop to mobile (with XMP) and back the location data is there and synchronized (via XMP file).

Also phone RAW (taken with different app) which have embedded location info do not provide way in Lightroom mobile to view/edit location data.